# SpringMVC not working in Netbeans 8.2 (maven build)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I'm new to J2EE and Spring framework.
I just want to start to employ this framework in Netbeans v.8.2 using Maven, but when I add Spring to the mix, it doesn't even deploy on GlassFish 4.

I made:

> File > new Project > Maven project > Web Application

because I wanted to add Spring in a second moment.

Then I added a **spring-conf.xml** file to configurate Spring, in /WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="alex.mawashi" />
     <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
</beans>
```

This is my **deployment descriptor**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <!-- declaration of dispatcher servlet (Single servlet of Spring MVC) -->    
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-conf.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   
    <!-- servlet-mapping of dispatcher servlet (Single servlet of Spring MVC) -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring-mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- end of servlet-mapping of dispatcher servlet (Single servlet of Spring MVC -->
</web-app>
```

This is my **pom.xml** file where all the dependencies have been downloaded correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>alex.mawashi</groupId>
<artifactId>MySpringMVCExample</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MySpringMVCExample</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring MVC dependencies-->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of spring MVC dependencies-->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my Controller:

```
package alex.mawashi.myspringmvcexample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class SpringFirstController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/gimmeResponseBody")
   @ResponseBody
   public String sayHello() {
      return "<p> Ciao! Questa risposta è direttamente ottenuta con il   @ResponseBody! </p>";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/")
   @ResponseBody
   public String kimoNO() {
      return "jspPage";
   }
}
```

I attach the screenshot of my project tree also.
[image]

It doesn't even deploy and this is the error:

> Grave:   Exception while loading the app
>
> Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /MySpringMVCExample
>
> Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 60; The prefix "context" for the element "context:component-scan" is not associated.

This is the link to the little project on GitHub: https://github.com/alessandroargentieri/MySpringMCVExample

So then, what am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your **spring-conf.xml** as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="alex.mawashi" />
     <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Also, it is recommended to remove the following from the pom file:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

And modify your request mapping in the web.xml like this:
`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: thanks, done but this is the error now: Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 60; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: the corresponding jolly character is rigorous but it's not possible to find a declaration of the element "context:component-scan".

Comment: Can you please make sure the XSD file versions match? In my example i was using 3.0, but maybe you were using newer, e.g. 4.0. That can cause errors too.

Comment: I've tried either 4.0 than 3.0 with no results unfortunately

Comment: Ok, I've edited the spring-conf.xml again according to the documentation and it works for me now.

Comment: Any luck with it?

Comment: Hi SaWo I changed some xmlns into spring-conf.xml and it deploys. But when it comes to access to the RequestMapping it doesn't work. I tested: http://localhost:8080/MySpringMVCExample/spring-mvc/gimmeResponseBody and also tried to remove the name of the WebApp with: http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc/gimmeResponseBody. But always 404 as response

Comment: Edit your pom.xml by adjusting the servlet-mapping: <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Comment: Sorry, insted of pom.xml i wanted to mention web.xml :)